# Show that $6(p-qm)(p+qm) \leq r^2 $ using Discriminant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, analytic-geometry, quadratics, discriminant

Given that line $y=mx+r $ meets the curve $\frac{y^2}{p^2}-\frac{x^2}{q^2}=6$,where $p,q,m, r$ are constants.

Show that $6(p-qm)(p+qm) \leq r^2 $

From $\frac{y^2}{p^2}-\frac{x^2}{q^2}=6$,

$q^2 y^2 - p^2 x^2 =6p^2 q^2 $ $-(1)$

So, subst. $y=mx+r$ into $(1)$ to get a mess of

$(q^2 m^2 -p^2)x^2 + 2q^2 mrx +r^2 -6p^2 q^2 =0$

For line to meet curve,
Discriminant $\geq$ $0$

$b^2 -4ac$ $\geq 0$

So it's

$(2q^2 mr)^2 - 4(q^2 m^2 -p^2)(r^2 -6p^2 q^2) \geq 0$

Continuing from here,

$q^4 m^2 r^2 -q^2 m^2 r^2 + 6p^2 q^4 m^2 +p^2 r^2 -6p^4 q^2 \geq 0$

Then I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:
$$(q^2 m^2 -p^2)x^2 + 2q^2 mrx +r^2 -6p^2 q^2 =0$$
The mistake in $r^2$.

It should be $r^2q^2$.

Comment: Ok lemme try that to see if it works
lol.Thanks that was the mistake all along hahahha

Comment: @Arc Neoepi Now it works!